# Is there a size limit in performing sfdx force:mdapi:convert?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, convert, mdapi, source

I am attempting to convert a large src directory in mdapi format into source format.  When I run "the sfdx force:mdapi:convert -r directoryToBeConverted -d directoryToCaptureConversion --loglevel FATAL" It get's hung up.

What's also giving me challenges is nothing is showing up in the $HOME/.sfdx/sfdx.log file when the conversion get's hung up.

I did some troubleshooting and removed the first half of the directory and performed the conversion and it worked.  The secondhalf of the directory ended up hanging again so I am continueing to break things down to figure out which metadata type is causing the conversion to hang.  From what I can tell right now, it seems to be the profile metadata type as it's size is 400 MB.

I can't share the exact directory so I apologize ahead of time.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not likely "hung", it just takes a while to convert large files, especially if you have a lot of Object files and/or Static Resources, as they have to be "decomposed." If there was an error, it would show an error and log it in the log. You need to be patient.

Comment: Lol FINE!! I'll be patient, thank you!!

Comment: @jschleicher That said, I agree there should be a "verbose" option or progress bar so you're not left wondering. I'll bring that up with the DX team.

Comment: that would be awesome thank you @sfdcfox!

Answer (score 0):

I usually ignore static resource while retrieving and converting. You are right it will just stop responding and fail.

Comment: good to know @VJ_Lightning_SFDX thank you!